# Scrub identifying data from USB stick

Tags: security, usb-drive, images, privacy, exif

I am providing photos related to a legal matter to a lawyer and she is going to give them to law enforcement without giving them my name (under attorney client privilege).

I am not sure if she is tech savvy so my plan is to give her a physical USB stick with JPG files on it, organized into a folder structure. I want to make sure that my identity is not discoverable from the stick or the files.

I use Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I am going to use `exiftool` to remove the metadata from the images. What can I do to make sure that no traceable data specific to my PC is left on the USB stick?

Comment: maybe a better place to ask is at https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: buy a $40 inkjet printer ... print the photos ... destroy the printer

Comment: Buy a new USB key, Accumulate your laundered `.jpg` files in a directory. If you're really paranoid, create another userid, use it to copy the files, delete userid,.

Comment: Absolutely, start with a brand new usb key! It is impossible to clear all old data from flash memory that uses over-provisioning; some blocks may get marked as having had too many writes and will be removed from the usable part of the device, to be replaced by spare blocks provisioned for this case. Forensic tools will probably still be able to read those inaccessible blocks. Always use encryption on flash drives.

Comment: I edited the nature of the legal matter from the post since you seem to be very concerned about privacy, but beware that it still is in the edit history.